# Read process memory failing to read the correct value?

Tags: c++, dll

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why this isn't working. I'm trying to display the local player health using some generic Read Process Memory template I've found on the internet. This is all from a dll which is injected into a process. The rpm and wpm template:

```
#include <cstdint>

template<typename TYPE>
TYPE RPM(HANDLE proc, DWORD address) {
    TYPE buffer;
    ReadProcessMemory(proc, (LPCVOID)address, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    return buffer;
}

template<typename TYPE>
void WPM(HANDLE proc, DWORD address, TYPE dataToWrite) {
    TYPE buffer = dataToWrite;
    WriteProcessMemory(proc, (LPVOID)address, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
}
```

Some things I declared:

```
HANDLE hProc;
uintptr_t client = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(TEXT("client.dll"));
constexpr ptrdiff_t LocalPlayer = 0xd3dd14;
constexpr ptrdiff_t m_iHealth = 0x100;
```

The code I used to read off the local player health:

```
int Health = RPM<int>(hProc, client + LocalPlayer + m_iHealth);
std::cout << Health << "\n";
```

It returns a really large negative number, which I believe is the minimum value an int can have. I cannot change m_iHealth to a DWORD because I'm using GetClientEntityList, which requires m_iHealth to be a constesxpr ptrdiff_t.

The only issues I could think of are:

1. RPM isn't taking a fully DWORD value in. -- Cannot fix
2. The type of RPM is an int, but that is what the value of health is in.
3. For whatever reason the template doesn't support constexpr ptrdiff_t's. If this is the case, could someone pass me a template that supports constexpr ptrdiff_t values?

What I've tried:

1. Declaring a new DWORD, localClient, as client + LocalPlayer, then reading from localClient and health.
2. This:

```
uintptr_t localPlayerAddr = RPM<uintptr_t>(hProc, client + LocalPlayer);
```

3. Declaring 2 as a DWORD.

The expected outcome: What I wanted to happen was for it to print to a console window (which it does) and show me the correct health value of the local player (which it doesn't). I've made sure to click the button that does this (Im using Dear ImGui) while the player is in the game. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've added checks to make sure the value exists and is an int, which both pass.

Comment: No return results are checked, so you need to add error checking and report any errors.

Comment: @RichardCritten I've added a check to make sure that the value is an int, and that it exists, and both pass, so I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: All of the calls to the Win32API functions eg `ReadProcessMemory`, `GetModuleHandle` etc  They can all fail. You need to read the documentation for each one for how to get the error code if it fails and then report it.

Comment: Is this a 32bit executable?

Comment: @ssbssa yes, what I'm injecting to is a 32 bit executable, and my dll is built as a 32 bit dll.